# Insert from one table into another (with extra values) (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Had a search but can only find stuff on inserting from one table to another.

I have this query which takes data from one table and inserts it into another:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders (product_id, customer_id) 
  SELECT product_id, customer_id FROM tbl_basket 
  WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
```

What I want to do is this with extra data included. For example I would insert the product_id and customer_id based of the other table, and insert extra values which are not located in another table.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders (product_id, customer_id, order_status) 
  SELECT product_id, customer_id, \'placed\' FROM tbl_basket 
  WHERE customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'"
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try the second query? don't you get a syntax error? you should because it is missing a comma!

Comment: you are missing a comma before `place` in your second query

Comment: Ah yes still the same issue. Just missed it when adding it here.

Comment: okay then what error does it say?

Comment: @AndreschSerj because he did not accept any answer to any of the questions he have that solve his problem, that link is the tour so he can learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want insert extra data into table, you can tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders (product_id, customer_id, order_status) 
SELECT product_id, customer_id, 'order_status' FROM tbl_basket 
WHERE customer_id = 'example'
```

If you have extra data in second table, you can join the second table like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders (product_id, customer_id, order_status) 
SELECT product_id, customer_id, t2.order_status FROM tbl_basket t1 
join tbl_basket2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.customer_id = 'example'
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I was close but not close enough! Cheers.